# Serving images in real time with request API in local environment

Tags: python, rest, request

I have a machine learning pipeline I want to serve images captured from local client's webcam through some sort of a request-response API. Note that both server and client will be running on the same machine.

First thing that came to my mind was REST API, so I tried to encode and decode frames in base64 but the latency was not very good.

```py
def encode_image(image):
    string = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)[1]
    string_encoded = base64.b64encode(string).decode()
    return string_encoded

def decode_image(encoded):
    string_decoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
    numpy_jpg = np.frombuffer(string_decoded, dtype=np.uint8)
    image = cv2.imdecode(numpy_jpg, flags=1)
    return image
```

What I'd like to do is to take advantage of the fact that the data does not have to be copied, since it is already present in memory. I'd imagine I could send the frame's memory address to the server and read it on the server side.

Is this possible in python? I'm open to any cython magic if necessary. For now I'm trying to make it work in pure python but later on I'd like to make requests from C++, meaning C++ program reads frames from webcam and serves them to python driven server.